# symfony2 assetic include assets from themes

Tags: php, symfony, themes, twig, assetic

I have a question about symfony2 assetic. The next situation in project:

We got a themes of project, themes must be stored in one folder. Now it's in:

```
/
/src
   /Dwd
      /FrontendBundle
        /Resources
          /themes
            /default
              /css
                reset.css
                style.css
              /img
                img.png
              layout.html.twig
            /not_default
              /css
                reset.css
                style.css
              /img
                img.png
              layout.html.twig
```

and i have the problem of including the styles and images from styles (cssrewrite) filter from theme

In layout.html.twig the next code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      {% stylesheets 'bundles/dwdfrontendbundle/css/*' filter="cssrewrite" %}
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
      {% endstylesheets %}
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

And when I do "php app/console assets:install" assetic don't install styles from Dwd/FrontendBundle/Resources/themes...

So my question is How i can add this path or include this css files in layout.html.twig of any file?

p.s. We extend this layout in /views templates trough adding include path to twig.loader service, like {% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}.

Comment: Just use another structure? ̀`Resources/views/Theme/foo.html.twig` and `Resources/public/css/theme.css`

Comment: I can't use another structure, cause the /Resources/themes is sub-repository, so for themes we got single repository (non project)